# Campaign Marketplace not working

Tags: campaign

[image: Campaign marketplace no results]

I already have campaign records, but I can't see anything in the component
I have salesforce license, and I am sys.admin
The marketing user check-box is checked 
It is in sandbox.
Thanks in advance for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:
No Start/End date was defined, and this component displays ACTIVE and campaigns that have today date between the start and the end date of the campaign